# An Operator Like Sturm-Liouville with Orthogonal Eigenfunctions

Tags: functional-analysis, orthogonality, sturm-liouville

Do we have any other operator like Sturm-liouville operator that give us real eigenvalues and orthogonal eigenfunctions? I know the Hermitian operators have this property but I like to see an example other than Sturm-Liouville. And what about non Hermitian ones?

Comment: Hermitian operators do not all have that property.

Comment: $H=L^2[0,1]$.  $Tf= \int_{0}^{1}K(x,y)f(y)dy$ where $\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1} |K(x,y)|^2dxdy < \infty$ and $K(y,x)=\overline{K(x,y)}$. This is another example.

Comment: @DisintegratingByParts I'm sorry i meant real eigenvalues and orthogonal eigenfunctions. the Hermitian operators all have this property and I don't understand your example exactly

Comment: The operator $Tf = xf(x)$ on $L^2[0,1]$ is Hermitian and has no eigenfunctions or eigenvalues. The spectrum is continuous and equal to $[0,1]$. Hermitian operators do not have the property you stated.

Comment: @DisintegratingByParts yes this operator doesn't have any eigenvalue or eigenfunction but IF it had they would have this property you can see this theorem in Al-Gwaiz's book Sturm-Liouville Theory and its Applications section 2.3 and even in wikipedia page about eigenfunctions here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenfunction

Comment: I don't think it's a reasonable to claim that $Tf=xf$ gives you real eigenvalues and orthogonal eigenfunctions. Do you?

Comment: @DisintegratingByParts well this operator is Hermitian but it doesn't have any eigenvalues. the theorem says that if the operator is hermitian all it's eigenvalues are real-valued but this one doesn't have any. so whats the problem?

Comment: Then, do you want examples of operators with no eigenvalues. There are several types of those. A Quasinilpotent operator is an example.

Comment: @DisintegratingByParts no I want an operator that has real eigenvalues and orthogonal eigenfunctions except Sturm-liouville operators. and I want to know if there is such an operator in non-hermitian ones

Comment: Do you want a basis of eigenfunctions with real eigenavalues? If you do, then the operator is Hermitian.

Comment: @DisintegratingByParts orthogonal basis. so you mean being hermitian is a necessary condition?

Comment: If you have a bounded operator that has an orthonormal basis of eigenvectors with real eigenvalues, then the operator is Hermitian. If it has an orthonormal basis with complex eigenvalues, then the operator is Normal.

Comment: @DisintegratingByParts thanks a lot this answers my question

Answer (score 1):

I can't tell from your post if you know it already, but there exists the spectral theorem for normal operators:

Let $(H, \langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle)$ a Hilbert space and $T: H \to H$ a compact, normal operator. Then $T$ is of the form
$$ Tx = \sum_{n} \lambda_n \langle x, e_n \rangle e_n \qquad \text{for all } x \in H$$
for a (maybe finite) sequence $(\lambda_n)_{n \in \mathbb N}$ in $\mathbb C \setminus \{0\}$ tending to $0$ and vectors $(e_n)_{n \in \mathbb N}$ in $H$ with

1. $T e_n = \lambda_n e_n$ for all $n \in \mathbb N$.
2. $\langle e_n, e_m \rangle = \delta_{n, m}$ for all $n, m \in \mathbb N$.

There are further interesting properties in the setting of the theorem. Also there are versions of the theorem with less assumptions to the operator (namely bounded instead of compact or even unbounded normal operators). I hope that was what you ask for :)

Comment: Yeah I've seen this theorem, I just need an example